# Redirect to action with an attribute in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to redirect from a controller method to another method in the same controller, by using `RedirectToAction`. However, it's not working so far.

One reason I can think of is the attribute route I have on my target method.

```
public class PostController : Controller
{
    private static readonly PostRepository postRepo = new PostRepository();

    [Route("post/{id}")]
    public ActionResult GetPost(int id)
    {
        Post post = postRepo.GetPostById(id);

        return View("Index", post);
    }

    [Route("post/{id}/comment")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void Comment(int id, string text)
    {
        Post post = postRepo.GetPostById(id);

        var comment = GetComment(text);

        postRepo.AddComment(comment);

        RedirectToAction("post", new { id });    // Didn't work

        RedirectToAction("GetPost", new { id });    // Didn't work
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have to return the result: `return RedirectToAction("GetPost", new { id });`

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, that worked! If you can post your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your case, you need to return the result:

```
return RedirectToAction("GetPost", new { id });
```